# Automating Access to Excel export

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-access

I have an access database file which gets updated every time when someone flashes their ID card to the card reader. I need this data to be exported to an excel file automatically on the go without any manual intervention so that when I try to get the excel report from a SCADA application I get the updated excel report from access database. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use Power Query to pull the data from the Access database. Set the query to refresh when the workbook is opened, and also use the setting to refresh the query periodically, like every 5 minutes, while the workbook is open.

Power Query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into Excel 2016 as Get and Transform.